# Issue with ytdl-core - discord.js (Lag on adding a new song)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

When my bot is playing music and someone adds a new song to the queue, the current song that is being played lags for a second or so. As far as i can tell it's due to downloading the infos about the song, but it's weird.
Does anyone know how to solve this out?

I'm executing the code in an asynchronous function

Comment: Also, i'm hosting my bot on a raspberry pi 4B (if that could be useful to find the issue)

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RGbYaKxy @Gpack

Answer (score 0):

I havent information about your source code, but probably you're using `yt-search` lib to search your command request, right?

If yes, this is the problem. This lib has **sync** process to parse the result html from youtube and its **block de node event loop.**

I recommend to use the [youtube v3 api.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). There is a lot of lib to use it:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search-without-api-key

I hope its help you.